# missed to pass in variable yes for interpolating in i18next

Tags: localization, i18next

```
</head>

<body>
    <div id="add">
        <div data-i18n="key">Hello</div>
    </div>
    <script>
        i18next.t('key', {yes: 'this', no: 'great'});
    </script>
    <script>
        i18next
        i18next.use(window.i18nextBrowserLanguageDetector)
        i18next.use(window.i18nextXHRBackend)

        .init({
            debug: true,
            tName: 't',
            handleName: 'localize',
            selectorAttr: 'data-i18n',
            targetAttr: 'i18n-target',
            optionsAttr: 'i18n-options',
            useOptionsAttr: true,
            parseDefaultValueFromContent: true,
            initImmediate: true,
            fallbackLng: false,
            interpolation: {
                "escapeValue": true,
                "prefix": "{{",
                "suffix": "}}",
                "formatSeparator": ",",
                "unescapePrefix": "-",
                "nestingPrefix": "$t(",
                "nestingSuffix": ")"
            },

            detection: {
                order: ['querystring', 'cookie', 'navigator', 'htmlTag'],
                lookupCookie: 'i18next',
                lookupLocalStorage: 'i18nextLng',
                caches: ['cookie'],
            },

            "backend": {
                "loadPath": "/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json"
            }

        }, function(err, t) {
            jqueryI18next.init(i18next, $);
            $('#add').localize();
        });

    </script>

</body>
```

Json file

{
 "key": "{{yes}} is {{no}}"

}

Console Result

i18next::interpolator: missed to pass in variable yes for interpolating {{yes}} is {{no}}

i18next::interpolator: missed to pass in variable no for interpolating  is {{no}}

Anything wrong in this code ?

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `i18next.t('key', {yes: 'this', no: 'great'});` before the initialization done.

You should:

```
.init({
       ...

```
    }, function(err, t) {
        jqueryI18next.init(i18next, $);
        // add vars here!!!
        $('#add').localize({yes: 'this', no: 'great'});
    });
```

```

Or use the data-i18n-option attribute: https://github.com/i18next/jquery-i18next#using-options-in-translation-function

Comment: @jamuhi, Thanks for your time , I have another query I tried translation in two different languages like Spanish or Chines I have two separate Json files. Then "yes" or "no" have two different values like for Spanish {yes: 'this is Spanish', no: 'Great Spanish'} or Chines {yes : 'this is Chines', no: 'Great Chines'}. But when I change browser language into Chines, Ch.json file call but still it display "this is Spanish is Great Spanish" should I change "{{yes}}" or "{{no}}" name is chines Json file ?

Comment: @AdityaTomar for that case you might want to try nesting: https://www.i18next.com/nesting.html

Comment: @jamuhi, Again tnx , Please look into this URL : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154275/not-able-to-translate-a-tag-inside-div-by-i18next-library